# getting error on SIR model and grid 2d graph

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to use the SIR model provided to ndlib to analyze how the epidemic behaves in a grid 2d network. The code below is my implementation

```py
import networkx as nx
import ndlib.models.ModelConfig as mc
import ndlib.models.epidemics as ep
from ndlib.viz.mpl.DiffusionTrend import DiffusionTrend

g3 = nx.grid_2d_graph(80,80) 
model3 = ep.SIRModel(g3)
cfg = mc.Configuration()
cfg.add_model_parameter('lambda',beta)
cfg.add_model_parameter("fraction_infected",0.05)
cfg.add_model_parameter('beta',0.9)
cfg.add_model_parameter('gamma',0.05)

model3.set_initial_status(cfg)
iterations3 = model3.iteration_bunch(500)
trends3 = model3.build_trends(iterations3)
```

The problem is when i try to get my configuration on the model, because it gives me this error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11068/1868465894.py in <module>
      7 cfg.add_model_parameter('gamma',0.05)
      8 
----> 9 model3.set_initial_status(cfg)
     10 iterations3 = model3.iteration_bunch(500)
     11 trends3 = model3.build_trends(iterations3)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ndlib\models\DiffusionModel.py in set_initial_status(self, configuration)
    173 
    174                 available_nodes = [n for n in self.status if self.status[n] == 0]
--> 175                 sampled_nodes = np.random.choice(available_nodes, int(number_of_initial_infected), replace=False)
    176                 for k in sampled_nodes:
    177                     self.status[k] = self.available_statuses['Infected']

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.choice()

ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? Thx for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nodes of your graph are not labeled as integers, when the other libraries try to access the graph they expect integers as node labels. The labelling of `nx.grid_2d_graph()` is done with tuples per default to allow selection via the grid (e.g. (0,0) or (10,10)). To make your code work, change the node labels to integers:

```
import networkx as nx
import ndlib.models.ModelConfig as mc
import ndlib.models.epidemics as ep
from ndlib.viz.mpl.DiffusionTrend import DiffusionTrend

g3 = nx.grid_2d_graph(80,80) 

#relabel the nodes:
g3 = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(g3, first_label=0)

model3 = ep.SIRModel(g3)

cfg = mc.Configuration()
cfg.add_model_parameter('lambda',0.4)
cfg.add_model_parameter("fraction_infected",0.05)
cfg.add_model_parameter('beta',0.9)
cfg.add_model_parameter('gamma',0.05)

infected_nodes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
cfg.add_model_initial_configuration("Infected", infected_nodes)

model3.set_initial_status(cfg)
iterations3 = model3.iteration_bunch(500)
trends3 = model3.build_trends(iterations3)
```